# How do I create a link but keep the content text-like?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a link with text in it but make it look like regular text at all times. For example, I want to make text inside my link look like the title of the post ie it's a clickable link but it looks like regular text instead of it looking like this

```html
<a href="#">this is a link</a>
```

I tried inspecting the title but it looks like a normal  tag with text in it but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
       color: black; }
    a {color: black; text-decoration: none;}
    a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<a href="#">hello</a>
```

Comment: I like this one. Didn't need any extra classes or id's. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the class attribute and then just style the class the same as your title's styling.

HTML

```
<a class='myClass' href="#">this is a link</a>
```

CSS

```
.myClass {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
}

.myClass:hover {
    /* put whatever styling you want when someone hovers over the link */
}
```